# Cassandra user defined type partition cell count limits

Tags: cassandra

If I have a user defined type as a column in a Cassandra table, do each of it's fields count toward the 2 billion cells per partition limit, or does the whole cell count as 1? I can't find anything anywhere mentioning this.

Answer (score 1):

All UDT data properties are stored all-together in a single cell, so the whole cell counts as 1.

Just to warn you, that limit (2 billion cells per partition) is kind of mis-understood.  Your partitions will probably become large and ungainly *long* before they approach 2 billion cells.  Knowing that limit exists is good to remember.  But it's a good idea to stay as far from that limit as possible.

Comment: thanks for the warning. I'm aware of that fact, but given the model and the pure volume of data we process i'm looking at partitions in 10s of millions (this after jumping through hoops further partition the data). So this kind of cost savings is relevant if it means a factor of 4. That being said the the kind of operations this will support are write once, bulk read and so will involve linear read of the partition not binary search. I hope this should be sufficiently performant?